# How to remove water radiator pipes?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hardwood-floor

I bought a house that contains water radiator units that were disconnected 10 years ago. I want to replace the hardwood floors and the radiator pipes are in the way.

I want to saw off the radiator pipes, drop them under the sub-floor, and leave the radiator in place (the cost/benefit of removing the radiator is too high).

I sawed off one of the pipes and to my surprise there was a bit of water left over in the pipe. I am worried that if dropping water-containing-pipes under the sub-floor will cause damage to any floor I place on top.

1. What is the best/safest way to remove the radiator pipes?
2. Is there any harm to leaving the pipes with water under the sub-floor?
3. Is it worth having a professional plumber take a look?

Comment: Are these copper base board mounted radiators or floor mounted cast iron units?

Comment: How are you heating the house now.

Comment: I watched the U-tube video and learned a lot. I have never seen an old system of radiators piped with plastic pipe that can be capped so easily and that to fully understand what is being said, I should move to England and learn how to understand fast talking  "English accent" people.

Comment: @mikes They are baseboard mounted radiators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: it looks like the best practice is to cap the pipe after sawing it off: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lBqLTvtVrw

Comment: That seems like quite a bit of effort and expese. I'd vacuum out the water and call it a day.

Comment: The pipes are almost certainly designed to drain to some lowest point, at least on each loop, so if you can find that point and drain them there, allowing air in from the radiator end, that may be clean and dry.

Comment: @Upnorth The lowest point is somewhere underneath the floors. I can't access it.